# Vue3 cannot get dom via attribute ref

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

```
     <template>
          <div class="music-list">
            <template v-if="songs.length">
              <scroll :options="scrollOptions" v-if="songs.length" @scroll="onScroll" ref="scrollRef">
                <song-list
                  v-if="songs.length"
                  :songs="songs"
                  :playlist="playlist"
                  class="song-list-ref"
                  @scroll="onScroll"
                >
                </song-list>
              </scroll>
            </template>
          </div>
     </template>
```

```
    const { songs, playlist, creator, resolvedIcons } = useRouterHook(Icons)
    const scrollRef = ref<any>(null)

    function onScroll(pos: any): void {
      const y: number = -pos.y
      console.log(scrollRef)
    }
```

When I tried to get `scrollRef.value`, it returned `true`, sometimes it will return `null`

I searched this question on the Internet, there is someone say that when you use `v-if`, you may not get the dom via ref. I have no solution to resolve it, please help me

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` will not be created until after the `v-if` is rendered from `false` to `true`.

Use `v-show` instead of `v-if` to ensure the element is always rendered.

Other options to track the `ref` when using `v-if`:

You can watch the condition, then use `nextTick` to get the `ref`.

```js
watch(()=>songs.length, value=>{
  if (value > 0) {
    nextTick(()=>{
       // use ref
    })
  }
})
```

Finaly, you can watch the ref itself

```js
watch(ref, value=>{
  if (value) {
  }
})
```